# Getting error when I Send a message to the RaycastHit object

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting

I have created a shooting game, here when I am shooting I have a c# script for damage for enemies.I have Used Raycast to Shoot enemies.if the RaycastHit becomes an enemy, it will be deducted it's health.It works properly.But the thing is, If I shoot objects except enemies it causes an error.
I have provided some details about that.this is the script,

```
public class DamageSMG : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int DamageAmount = 5;
    public float TargetDistance;
    public float AllowedRange = 50;
    public RaycastHit Shot;
    public int Firing;
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("Fire1")){
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward),out Shot))
            {
                TargetDistance = Shot.distance;
                if (TargetDistance < AllowedRange)
                {
                    if (Firing == 0)
                    {
                        Deduct();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void Deduct()
    {
        Firing = 1;
        Shot.transform.SendMessage("DeductPoints", DamageAmount);
        StartCoroutine(Wait());

    }
    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        Firing = 0;
    }
}
```

I am using an machine gun.therefore I have created Script to fire coutinously with 0.1sec break.When I press **Fire1** button, The RayCastHit Object is received a message where the method called **DeductPoints** with the **DamageAmount**.As this Script my enemies are deduct point 5 by 5 every hit.Then Destroy the object.The Enemy script is this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int EnemyHealth = 20;
    void DeductPoints(int DamageAmount)
    {
        EnemyHealth -= DamageAmount;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (EnemyHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            GlobalScore.GlobalScorecount += 1;
        }

    }

}
```

But my problem is when I shoot objects except Enemies(Ex: walls),The console gives an error.The error is like this
*SendMessage DeductPoints has no receiver*
How can I solve this error or is there any other way of Deducting enemy health with raycast?
I can play the game with this error in UnityEngine.but it is not possible to Build the game.Please help me to Solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered making `DeductPoints` `public`, then calling it directly like so:

```
public void Deduct()
{
    Firing = 1;
    var enemy = Shot.transform.GetComponent<EnemyScript>();
    if(enemy == null)
        return; // Not an enemy! Abort!

    enemy.DeductPoints(DamageAmount);
    StartCoroutine(Wait());
}
```

This has a number of advantages: calling the method directly saves you the reflection cost of searching for a method called "DeductPoints" on every component of the hit object. It allows you to send more than one argument if you need (like a damage type, or damage-dealer reference), and receive a return value about the result. And it's visible to the IDE and compiler so they can do things like compile-time type checking, or refactoring to rename the method and all references to it automatically.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it pays to avoid "stringly typed" code, where you specify the thing you want using text in quotation marks. This is often much slower and prone to more bugs than the alternatives.